# How to make program like this without logical operator ? (&& or and)

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x,y,z;

    printf ("Side x: ");
    scanf ("%d",&x);

    printf ("Side y: ");
    scanf ("%d",&y);

    printf ("Side z: ");
    scanf ("%d",&z);

    if (x+y>z&&x+z>y&&z+y>x)
        printf ("\nTriangle can be performed");
    else
        printf ("\nTriangle cannot be performed");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can do it, but why would you want to?

Comment: this is `C` not `C++`, so why `C++` tag? Change this to `C` tag.

Comment: This isn't a place to write code or do your homework for you.  We'll help with problems you've encountered, but you have to show effort.

Comment: @Joel This isn't my HW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested `if` statements.

```
triangle = false;
if (x + y > z) {
    if (x + z > y) {
        if (z + y > x) {
            triangle = true;
        }
    }
}
if (triangle) {
    printf("\nTriangle can be performed");
} else {
    printf("\n Triangle cannot be performed");
}
```